# how to use bazaar to access the same folder on 2 computers

Tags: java, python, version-control, cloud-hosting

hey guys, i use two computers frequently, a laptop with ubuntu 10.10 and a pc with windows 7. i want to be able to access the folders from both pc's. then programming will be less annoying. someone told me bazaar was the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to make programming on two computers "less annoying," you probably are looking for some version control system.  Bazaar (`bzr`) is one such system, as are Subversion (`svn`), Mercurial (`hg`), and Git (`git`).

All of these systems will make it easy for you to record your changes on one computer and apply them (ie, play them back) on the other computer.  They'll also allow you to see a history of every change you make, which is nice.

My personal preference is `git`, but I have no idea what the state of `git` support on Windows is.  That being the case, **I'd recommend that you look into Mercurial**, because I know for sure that it works well on the two platforms you mentioned.  Check out [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for free Mercurial source code hosting, and you won't even have to deal with setting up a server to use!

By the way, there is good, free source code hosting for all of the VCSes I have mentioned:

- [GitHub](http://github.com/) for Git
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com) for Subversion
- [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/) for Bazaar (this is probably the least user-friendly of the three)

Answer (score 0):

[Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) is a [`versioning control system`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), although it can do what you want it's probably overkill for your purpose.

What you seem to be looking for is a filesharing solution such as [`dropbox`](http://www.dropbox.com/), [`live mesh`](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx), [`spideroak`](https://spideroak.com/) etc., which lets you sync files between computers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish your goal is probably to use [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/).  You may then run a version control system over your shared folder is you wish.